# Calling alarm intent in a loop?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to call the alarm intent repeatedly like I showed in the code below but it is only getting called once. i.e is only the first alarm is getting set. Before the loop is ends I am increasing i value by 4. This is basically code for setting 3 alarms with a gap of 4 minutes.

```
                     for(int j=0;j<3;j++) {
                     Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
                     intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, mess);
                     intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, result);
                     intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, i);
                     startActivity(intent);
                    i=i+4;
                 }
```

I also tried startActivities function that didn't serve my purpose.
The intents have to activate the alarms.
Is there any way through which I can run that intent a specific number of times?
That number will be a variable whose value will be provided by the user.Can anyone please answer this fast.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?with a gap of 4 minutes the alarm should go on 3 times?

Comment: I am thinking of customizing the snooze feature, I just took 4 and 5 for representational purpose. I will replace them with variables.